# How to check appointments on calendars shared with other than ALL details option?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to check appointments in shared calendars of my coworkers.

```
Set MyRecipient = myNameSpace.CreateRecipient("NAME")
Set oCalendar = Application.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(MyRecipient, olFolderCalendar)
Set oItems = oCalendar.Items
```

This works for calendars shared with ALL details. I cannot check calendars shared with start/end, topic of the meeting, room (most common method).

Is there a command similar to `GetSharedDefaultFolder` or do I have to adjust something in this code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are going to be limited to what they have their settings set to. That's why those settings exist.

Answer (score -1):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything else for that.